# How do you select Arcs inside a boundary in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis, geometric-arc, multilinestring

I'm searching an answer for this question and all I found on

http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3/ch04.html#id2572194

is

```
SELECT road_id, road_name 
FROM roads 
WHERE roads_geom && GeomFromText('POLYGON((...))',-1);
```

should I put the boundary vertexes in this SQL replacing the  '...' ?

Answer (score 1):

assuming your arc is not inside a postgis geometry object, yes. You would construct a polygon in Well Known Text (WKT) representation:

My best guess would be you need the linestring:

LINESTRING((1 1, 1 2, 1 3, 1 4))

where you put the nodes on the arc in sequence, reconstructing a rough representation of the original arc.